# SQL not working in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a bit of a quandary here, no matter what I try I cannot get a simple SQL statement to return the correct result for me.

This for example works fine and dandy:

```
$sql = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query(mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','','recruitment'), "SELECT COUNT(`id`) as 'result' FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} {$value}"));
```

Yet when I use a similar approach with this I get a null result

```
function coExists($name){
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','rec_spec'); 
    $sql = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(`id`) AS 'result' FROM `companies` WHERE `name`='.$name.'"));
    //return $sql['result']; <--Returns zero
    print_r($sql); // <--Returns Array ( [result] => 0 )
}
```

I have tried the `name` bit without the single quotes, in curly braces and everything I can possibly think of.  I also tried just hard coding a name I know exists and it works fine. Where am I going wrong??

Many thanks for any assistance

Dave

Comment: `AS 'result'` is wrong. Column name aliases are identifiers and belong in backticks. And `='.$name.'"` isn't a valid string concatenation, as everything is already interpolated within double quotes. Also google for parameter binding, then switch to PDO.

Comment: You define a different database in your second set of code than you do in your first.

Comment: Yes I do refer to different databases, this is due to one set of code working on one DB perfectly fine yet the second return zero always.  If I switch to no concatenation or {$name} then I get - Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in....Error

Answer (score 1):

change your query

```
$sql = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(`id`) AS 'result' FROM `companies` WHERE `name`='.$name.'"));
```

to

```
$sql = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(`id`) AS 'result' FROM `companies` WHERE `name`='$name'"));



function coExists($name){
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','rec_spec'); 
    $sql = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(`id`) AS 'result' FROM `companies` WHERE `name`='$name'"));
    //return $sql['result']; <--Returns zero
    print_r($sql); // <--Returns Array ( [result] => 0 )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this function and see configuration of your server and check mysqli is installed or not .

```
<?php
echo phpinfo();
?>
```

[image]

or

Debug your query by echo statement and check manually this query return a result or not:

```
echo $sql = "SELECT COUNT(`id`) AS 'result' FROM `companies` WHERE `name`='.$name.'";
```